definition of dimension of a topological space
I apologize for this trivial question. The dimension of a topological space is the supremum of the length of ascending chains of irreducible closed subsets.
Question. Why don't we define it to be the supremum of the length of descending chains of such subsets?
My thoughts. When the dimension is finite, I believe that both definitions coincide. However, there are Noetherian spaces (Example 2.26.b of Gathmann's AG notes) and rings (Nagata) that are not of finite dimension. By defining it this way (as the sup of lengths of ascending chains), we can prevent from identifying "essentially different" spaces. Otherwise, all Noetherian spaces would have finite dimensions. Are there any other reasons for doing this?
Thank you for any comments.

Since the definition is only about finite sequences, the two are exactly the same. Given a finite sequence, you can view it either as an increasing or decreasing sequence. It's not like in the definition of a Noetherian/Artinian ring which involves infinite sequences, and then it is really not the same.

@Mark Thank you. I confused myself!
